# Automate build for different configurations UWP-Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have a UWP App solution file, which I need to build for 15 different set of configuration parameters present in `AppResources.resw.`
For e.g :

```
For build 1 : param 1 value in AppResources.resw should be abc
for build 2 : param 2 value in AppResources.resw. should be xyz.
```

How can we automate this build for different configurations in Visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the following article on multi-branding solved my problem.
[http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1087]